# RegEx how to match everything exclude a string in a function

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I exclude a string from the match in regex?

Input:

```
functionXY("Hello World");
```

Match:

```
functionXY();
```

i got this far with my regex expression:

```
/functionXY[(][)][;]/gm
```

but can't find the correct expression to exclude the string "Hello World" in the match.

Comment: 1. It is important to realise that each match of a regular expression is of a consecutive sequence of characters only. 2. Why are you using the `m` flag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to match everything inside the brackets, then use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
const str = 'functionXY("Hello World");';

const regex = /(?<=functionXY[(]).+(?=[)][;])/gm;

const res = str.replace(regex, '')
console.log(res)
```

Comment: `/(?<=functionXY\()"[^"]*"(?=\);)/`

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `functionXY[(][)][;]` uses square brackets for single characters and only matches `functionXY();`

Instead you can use 2 capture groups to capture what you want to keep, and match the double quotes and all chars other than double quotes that you don't want to keep.

In the replacement use 2 capture groups `$1$2`

```
(functionXY\()"[^"]*"(\);)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Veesob/1)

Comment: I'd say `functionXY\((.*?)\);` is better since it can work for `functionXY();` and `functionXY("Hello World");`

Comment: @EphellonDantzler But when it is `functionXY()` then there is nothing to replace and already ok.

Comment: Then it'll replace nothing and will do nothing; if it's in a loop, just use `.+` (one or more) instead of `.*` (zero or more)

Comment: @EphellonDantzler But I think the question is about a string, so in that case you can match the double quotes and use a negated character class instead of a non greedy dot. I can also be wrong of course. You can post your answer as well.

Comment: Yeah, assuming OP wants to only include functions with strictly formatted strings your answer would be the best approach

Comment: @qianfranco what do you mean by that?

Comment: It should be also possible to filter a var. For Example:
var a = 3;
functionXY("Ouput: "+ a); // -> Output: 3

Comment: @qianfranco That is a bit of a broad requirement. Why do you want to use a regex for that?